# How to extract the whole part if part of it match the regex?

Tags: regex

For example:

```
/ticket2243/asd
```

The string can be split by / into two parts. I know that `\d{3,}` can match `2243`. But how to extract the whole part `/ticket2243` using regex?

Comment: Is the symbol splitting the string always / ?

Comment: @BenOng  Yes, the splitting symbol is always '/'

Comment: You may use this regex `^\/[^/]+`

Answer (score 1):

Regex:    `\/\w{3,}\d{3,}`

will get `/ticket2243` of `/ticket2243/asd`.

Comment: Except you don't need to escape a forward slash - it has no special regex meaning

Answer (score 1):

You can try that:

```
/[^/]+(?=/)
```

Explanation:

1. `/` matches the first occurrence of `/`
2. `[^/]+` capture everything but '/' where + indicates one or more
3. `(?=/)` it ensures that the whole thing is followed by another
   forward slash but you may ignore or remove this as well. But having this ensures that /asd is not matched.

By using that you get:

```
/ticket2243
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JMCoPQ/5)

In case you need all part like that then you may  use:

```
/[^/]+
```

now you get two matches :

```
1)  /ticket2243
2)  /asd
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/JMCoPQ/6)

Answer (score 0):

Try below regex !

^ shows that the first character must be '\' .

[] show the character class and inside it represent that everything is to be extracted but not '\' .

' * ' donated that multiple times.

After that you extracted before the '/'.

```
(^\/)[^\/]*(?=\/)
```

I am also attached the screenshot of the output .
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

If your data you want to match looks like:

forward slash, lowercase characters followed by digits...you could match it like this:

[`^/[a-z]+\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/ixKb3o/1/)

**Explanation**

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Match a forward slash `/`
- Match a lowercase character one or more times `[a-z]+`
- Match a digit one or more times `\d+`

If you just want to match from the first forward slash until the next forward slash, you could do it like this (as @anubhava suggested in his comment):

[`^/[^/]+`](https://regex101.com/r/A5maFh/1)

**Explanation**

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Match a forward slash `/`
- Match until you encounter a forward slash one or more times `[^/]+`